# How to Connect Apache Hive with ODBC and MIT Karberos using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hive, ssis, odbc, cloudera

Please help me.

I was create ssis package on visual studio 2012 to get data from Hive Apache, to connect the database i am using ODBC with Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive,  Mechanism with MIT Karberos. When i was execute package from visual studio / project there's no error, but when i am execute package using vb.net application i am getting error bellow :

```
There was a error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server
```

In the dts connectionString i was called DSN name and
Run64bitruntime i was set to false.
The ODBC connection was successfully connect and ticket Karberos is running oke.

When i try to test status connection is open or closed, i am getting error bellow :

my connection method call :

```
    Dim conn As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection 
    conn.ConnectionString = "Dsn=HiveSystem32;" 
    conn.Open()

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then   
       myLog.Info("Connection HiveSystem32 = Open") 
    ElseIf conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then 
       myLog.Info("Connection HiveSystem32 = Closed") 
    End If
```

Log Error :
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (34) Error from server: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No credentials cache found).

The log error like error when i am test connection ODBC which the ticket Karberos is Destroyed or no ticket running.

Thks.

Comment: Why would you check `ConnectionState` when you just opened it the line before?

Comment: @Mary I just want to know there is an error or not when opening a connection, and it turns out when opening a connection an error message appears

Comment: When you call conn.Open() you will know.

Comment: @Mary oke thks, can you give me solution how to connect hadoop with authentication MIT Karberos? I am stuck now.